# Make typescript arg optional depending on condition

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make the function argument optional depending on some template condition. If my generic type is `null`, I want some argument of my function to be optional, otherwise - mandatory.

I realised that type `T | void` is same as making it optional:

```
function f(arg: number | void) {}
f(2);
f(); // << works
```

Thus, I made a helper type:

```
type OptionalIf<S, T> = S extends null ? (T | void) : T;
```

And now I have a function of following type:

```
function f<S = null>(arg: OptionalIf<S, number>) {
}
```

BUT

```
f(2);
f(); // Fails
```

Why? When I hover on the type in VScode, it seems that it correctly detects arg's type (`number | void`), but it's still asking for an argument...

Comment: Like this? [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA8hEBLA9gOwIYBsCSAzAHgGUAaGAFQD4YBeGImKADxCjQBMBnGNAVyywwA-DADa5IQF0YALjHlJAbmB5eaAMbJ0MQgzp8BlABQA6M6IBukuQi2ZcusnwC2AIygAnSgEoYAb2AAXxUjACZvZTwjCOAVAk4QDyQ0AHNjcMj4xOS06MUgA)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
type OptionalIf<S, T> = S extends null ? [arg?: T] : [arg: T]


function f<S = null>(...arg: OptionalIf<S,number>) {
}
```

Comment: I want it to be optional ONLY if S = null, not always :)

Comment: I've edited the answer. Sorry for the misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 0):

By going with that helper type I feel that you're only complicating things. Unless I'm missing something, you should be able to keep it simple and have it like this:

```
function f<S = null>(arg: S | void) {}
```

And then just use it like this:

```
f(); // << works
f<null>(); // << works

f(2); // << works
f('3'); // << works

f<number>('4'); // fails, as expected
f<string>(5); // fails, as expected
```

---

Here's a TS Playground link where I've tested it ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAZUQXkWEAbPAPgAoBDAJwHMAuRDAH0QDc4YATASkQG8BfAKH7BiHANyIA9BMQoUiAO5xyAawDOQlLgIkxk6bIVK1g1FqLEAjACYAzLqky5wUjDyqANIlKrEAUwAeAA6%200L5sJsRW9vpyiirqwgDkNonRjobxJpogALYARr7kJIkALKniDs6uHl4%20AcGh4aiqUOQwYJQkAKxpVW6e3n5BIVBhQA)).